# Cisco Router and TP-LINK Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, router

I would like to know if it's possible to use the Cisco Router with TP-LINK switch.

I have three switch T1600G 28-TS , and to assure Internet redundancy in the new office i will place them, i was thinking about ordering 2 Cisco router to use the HSRP protocol. The final network capability should be about 250-300 computer, so i was seeking advice.

Thanks guys.

Edit : For now, we will go on two internet providers, with half of the users on one line and the other half on the second one. I plan to buy four 48 port switch to be able to have those 250 computers working at the same time (i already have three 24 ports switch and one 48 ports switch).

Comment: Thank you so much for you'r answer, yeah i wanted to know if Cisco router and TP Link switches are compatibles.
I know it seems light, but i have 3 of these which are 24 ports and one which is 48 ports.
I will just buy more to make it works. Or maybe i will buy a bigger switch but i don't have that much knowledge on such heavier equipment. Thanks again !

Comment: Just understand that consumer-grade devices, e.g. TP-Link, are off-topic here.

Comment: I don't understand you'r comment Ron Maupin.

Comment: In the [help/on-topic], it says, "_hardware that has a paid support option (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class devices)_." Unfortunately, TP-Link does not offer such such an option for its hardware, so the TP-Link equipment is off-topic here.

Comment: Oh ok i'am sorry, i will not ask any more questions thanks for the help anyway i got nice answer that helped me. Thanks guys.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

As a generalisation, I'd say half-a-dozen smaller switches is better than only a few larger and more powerful switches.  It's simple, and growth is in smaller chunks.

HSRP is good and not difficult.  But be very wary of putting in fault-tolerance you're not monitoring -- it's very easy to be lulled into a sense of security ("it's okay, we have HSRP") when perhaps one of them has been off for a year.

Think carefully about any complexity that you're adding, and when thinking of risks, don't allow yourself just to think that all downtime is bad.  "Mean Time To Repair" is often much more important than "Mean Time To Failure".

A good frequently-tested and well-maintained UPS is often worth much more than all the work that goes into redundant protocols.

Consider whether you're trying to protect principally against line outage or router outage.

Consider half the switches/users going to one router, half to the second, with some very easy method to move the users.  When you reject this, ask yourself how you'll test and monitor the HSRP.

Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify, im not sure what the question is you're asking.

if the question is it will HSRP work with a TP-LINK switch, then yes, just make sure that both routers can see the same VLAN you are attempting to provide HSRP,  if you are looking at HSRP for multiple VLANS, you'll need a dot1q trunk from the switches to the routers.

as a side note, this is basically a £100 switch, you might be asking a lot for attaching 250-300 hosts.